# I have a program to find the amount of alphabets in a string but its not complete can you complete it python

Tags: python

```
def encode(source):
    dest="";
    i=0
    while i<len(source):
        runLength = 1;
        while source[runLength] == source[runLength-1]:
            runLength=runLength+1
            i=i+1
        dest+=source[i]
        dest+=str(runLength)
        i=i+1
    return dest


source = raw_input("")
print (encode(source))
```

sample input:

```
AABBCCCCDADD
```

sample output:

```
3A2B4C3D
```

please fix it, mostly changing line 6 should do it I think

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. It's pretty easy to solve, as you can see from the answers, but if you want to learn python, you're probably better off debugging your own problems, and then ask specific questions about them when you run into some problem you can't figure out. Read more here: [ask]

Comment: Fixed: `import itertools; encode = lambda source: ''.join('{}{}'.format(len(list(group)), char) for char, group in itertools.groupby(source)); print(encode(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it using `dictionary`.

```
x="AABBCCCCDDD"
d={}
for i in x:
    d.setdefault(i,0)
    d[i]=d[i]+1
print "".join([str(j)+i for i,j in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a `dict` to keep the count, an OrderedDict will also keep the order for you:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def encode(source):
    od = OrderedDict()
    # iterate over input string
    for ch in source:
        # create key/value pairing if key not alread in dict
        od.setdefault(ch,0)
        # increase count by one each time we see the char/key
        od[ch] += 1
    # join the key/char and the value/count for each char
    return "".join([str(v)+k for k,v in od.items()])  

source = "AABBCCCCDDD"
print (encode(source))
```

This will only work for strings like your input where the chars don't repeat later, if they do we can keep track in a loop and reset the count when we meet a char that was not the same as he previous:

```
def encode(source):
    it = iter(source)
    # set prev to first char from source
    prev = next(it)
    count = 1
    out = ""
    for ch in it:
        # if prev and char are equal add 1 to count
        if prev == ch:
            count += 1
        # else we don't have sequence so add count and prev char to output string
        # and reset count to 1
        else:
            out += prev + str(count)
            count = 1
        prev = ch
    # catch out last match or a single string
    out += prev + str(count)
    return out
```

Output:

```
In [7]: source = "AABBCCCCDDDEE"

In [8]: print (encode(source))
A2B2C4D3E2
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, there is a Python library called `itertools` that has a function which is useful in this situation. It can split your string up into groups of the same letter.

```
import itertools

def encode(source):
    return "".join(["%u%s" % (len(list(g)), k) for k,g in itertools.groupby(source)])

print encode("AABBCCCCDDD")
```

This will print out the following:

```
2A2B4C3D
```

To see how this works, see the following smaller version:

```
for k, g in itertools.groupby("AABBCCCCDDD"):
    print k, list(g)
```

This prints the following:

```
A ['A', 'A']
B ['B', 'B']
C ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
D ['D', 'D', 'D']
```

You can see `k` is the key, and `g` is the group. If we take the length of each group, you have your solution.